# getting just 1 element from data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to use the data.table package in order to try to save memory on my data frame (which is 1.8 gig), but I'm having some difficulties with reading just 1 element. when using a data.frame, I would read the element by using the first call, and I would get the value as shown in the second call, without the need for the as.numeric() conversion. Since data.table inherits data.frame, I was expecting the same to be the case. Am I missing something?

```
DT = data.table(x=letters[1:3], y=1:9)
> DT[1,2]
   y
1: 1
> as.numeric(DT[1,2])
[1] 1
```

Comment: I did check those out, but I did not see how to read a single item.
It appears the FAQ has the answer though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution of using `as.numeric()` works ... as long as the data is in fact numeric, or can be coerced.

But you *can* use the fact that `data.table` cleanly subclasses `data.frame`:

```
R> DT <- data.table(x=letters[1:3], y=1:9)
R> DT[1,2]
   y
1: 1
R> unlist(DT[1,2]) ## DF is a list of vectors, so start with `unlist)_`
y 
1 
R> unname(unlist(DT[1,2]))  ## an `unname()`
[1] 1
R>
```

This should work equivalently for non-numeric or non-integer data.

Comment: I'm flummoxed by the output your session is producing.  Do you have some option set to ensure `with=T`?

Comment: No. Standard data.table 1.10.4. No special settings.

Comment: I seem to recall that the 'column by index' thingie is a very recent addition. "In by popular demand" or some such.

Comment: Ah, I thought I was going crazy (I was running this on 1.9.6).  Matt and co. are a bit more comfortable changing behavior than I am.

Answer (score 2):

It seemed that [`data.table` faq](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#j-num) have been updated. The very first answer is about this:

> 1.1 Why do DT[ , 5] and DT[2, 5] return a 1-column data.table rather than vectors like data.frame?

For the original question, I think it's easier just use this

```
> DT[1,2]
   y
1: 1
> DT[1,2][[1]]
[1] 1
```

Comment: Probably simplest to flip it around `DT[[2]][1]`, explained also in FAQ 1.1

Comment: Yes that also works. Though I'd prefer the `[i,j]` syntax in most cases, only use the `$` when I need the whole vector or `[[]]` when I'm using variable.

Answer (score 1):

Data.table does not like it when you refer to a column by column number and wants you to refer to it by name. The easiest way is to do as such:

```
DT = data.table(x=letters[1:3], y=1:9)
> DT[1,y]
[1] 1
```

Comment: That's not really the right inference (re what it "likes"), since `DT[1, "y"]` is also referring to it by name...